# Android : View Internal storage file in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a swf file which was created in Internal storage memory of android.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sample.swf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Is there any way to refer(embed) this file in my html page of webview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving the path to internal storage file where needed as for above swf: **"file:///data/data/--my_package_name--/files/sample.swf"**

For embedding swf following lines worked:

```
<object width="100" height="100">
<param name="movie" value="file:///data/data/<package_name>/files/sample.swf">
<embed src="file.swf" width="100" height="100">
</embed>
</object>
```